# How to implement offline mode on android

Tags: android, json, offline-caching

We load lots of data as JSON objects to some arrays in our application and this is handled while online. but now we would like to move to some kind of caching, how can we implement off line mode with Android?, is there an external storage I can write to?, there could be thousands of records.

Comment: Check out the documentation on storage http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) for caching objects. [Here's an example](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) on how to cache bitmaps for example.

Comment: nice, does this persist if in offline mode?

Comment: Of course. When no internet connection is available, it should fetch the data from the cache.